# Parse simple XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

How to parse the following xml as recordset?

```
<root>
    <240>0</240>
    <241>1</241>
    <242>2</242>
    <243>3</243>
    <249>4</249>
</root>

<root 240="0" 241="1" 242="2" 243="3" 249="4"/>
```

When I try

```
declare @ids xml = N'<root><240>0</240><241>1</241></root>'

SELECT T.Item.value('240[1]', 'int') 
from @ids.nodes('/root') AS T(Item)
```

I get an error

> ML parsing: line 1, character 8, illegal qualified name character: declare @ids xml = N'<240>0' SELECT T.Item.value('a[1]', 'int') from @ids.nodes('/root') AS T(Item)

But generally I need the following output:

```
|240|0|
|241|1|
...
```

When xml elements are named as usual everything is Ok (`<row key=240 value="0"/>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML [disallows](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp) to use numbers as first character of an element name. Use format from your example:

```
<row key=240 value="0"/>
```